# Javascript promises - catch with/without function

Tags: javascript, promise, console.log

I just started learning JavaScript and promises some hours ago, and I'm starting to get the "flow", but a couple of details are still unclear. Let's look at the following example:

```
function OnRejected(var){  
    return console.log("This is an error " + var)  
}

Promise.reject(2).then(function(a){return a*2})  
    .then(function(a){return a+5})  
    .then(function(a){return a*3})  
    .then(console.log)  
    .catch(OnRejected)
```

Result of the above code: This is an error 2
The example above works just fine. My question is: If I don't call a function and I try to directly call "console.log("this is an error")" inside the catch, why does it fail? Like this:

```
Promise.reject(3).then(function(a){return a*2})
    .then(function(a){return a+5})
    .then(function(a){return a*3})
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log("This is an error"))
```

With the result being:

*(node:39515) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: 3*
This is an error
*(node:39515) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)

(node:39515) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Process finished with exit code 0*

More than "promises" I believe my lack of knowledge is about functions in JS, console.log and console.log("whatever"). Any help or advice is really appreciated.

Comment: `.catch` accepts a *function*, not an invocation that doesn't return a function. change to `() => console.log(...`

Comment: The `catch()` call expects a function.

Comment: So, a function that returns "console.log("something")" and directly "console.log("something" are not the same?  
My programming skills are a little bit rusted, and my main programming language was java, but I remember "int function(){return 3} and "int a = 3" acting more or less the same.

Anyway, thanks a lot for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`catch()` and `then()` expect to receive a function as argument. In your example, `OnRejected` is a function, while `console.log("This is an error")` is not.

To explain a bit more : `console.log` is a function but `console.log('something')` is the result of the execution of the function`console.log` with the argument `'something'`.

To go back to `catch()` and `then()`, they will call the method you give it (in your example: `OnRejected`) and call it with, as an argument, whatever was return by the previously resolved promise.

Example :

```
getDataFromDistantServer().then(function (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    return otherCallToOtherServer()
}).then( function (dataFromOtherServer) => {
    console.log(dataFromOtherServer)
})
```

This would also work because `doSomething` is a function:

```
var doSomething = function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    return otherCallToOtherServer()
}

getDataFromDistantServer()
    .then(doSomething)
    .then( function (dataFromOtherServer) => {
        console.log(dataFromOtherServer)
    })
```

**Side note** : naming convention for your function `OnRejected` would dictate to not start the name with a capital letter and call it `onRejected`

Comment: "console.log if a function but console.log('something') is the result of the execution of the functionconsole.log with the argument 'something'."  
I had this idea in mind, but not clear enough to be able to completely understand it. Thanks a lot for the clear and full explanation, and for the side advice!